# what to do with this japanesed android system

Tags: lg, operating-system

So I received a phone as a gift but it turns out that at boot up is perfect japanese. We manage to set it up and change the language settings.

Yet, most of the applications are hard-installed (you can't remove) and even the keyboard is "japanese English(US)".

The phone barely connects to the network (low signal, -111DBm) and the mobile network state is Disconnected even though mobile data is on.

I am thinking of flashing a new Android Operative system. The phone is LG ISAI and the company that hard installed software (apart from Google) is [Au](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_(mobile_phone_company)).

Any help on what to do about it? (I won't sell it.)

Comment: Check the supported LTE bands and compare them to the bands used by your MNO in your country. If they don't match it doesn't matter which software you install, the reception will always be your problem.

Comment: @Robert would a hard reset help ? https://techviral.net/android-secret-codes/

Comment: @Robert  couldnt get a single code to work and show me any information. idk how to check the LTE bands

Comment: LTE bands are usually documented at some hardware spec collecting sites like GSMArena. Not sure if there is a way to query them in the phone.